# Common bindable interface

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, interface, datatable

What it makes that collections are bindable? Is there common interface for `List`, `DataTable` with can bind to same control?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To explain how `List<T>` and `DataTable` work (the footnote of the question), read the following but noting that:

- `List<T>` implements `IList` and has a `public T this[int index] {get;}` which is used for resolving metadata
- `DataTable` implements `IListSource`, which provides the table's default `DataView`; the `DataView` implements `IList`, and implements `ITypedList` to provide metadata

---

Collections bind in the following order:

- the source is tested for `IListSource`; if available the `IList` is obtained via `GetList()`
- otherwise the source is tested for `IList`; if unavailable an exception is thrown

then metadata for the `IList` is queried:

- the `IList` is tested for `ITypedList`; if available this is used via `GetProperties`
- the `IList` is tested for a public typed (non-object) indexer, i.e. `public Foo this[int index] { get; }` - if found, `Foo` is implied as the type and metadata obtained via `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Type)`
- else the first item (if non-empty) is queried via `GetType()` for the type, and metadata obtained via `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Type)`

we now have access to the items (`IList`) and their metadata; additional support (optional) is provided via `IBindingList` (provides 2-way binding and basic sorting etc), `IBindingListView` (provides advanced sorting, filtering, etc), `ICancelAddNew` and `IRaiseItemChangedEvents`.

For most common scenarios (show data and push changes back) `List<T>` is fine; if you need to show unrelated updates as they  happen `BindingList<T>` helps - but note that to support *member* level updates (as opposed to just add/remove/etc) the `T` must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

For reference, "metadata" here means "a set of `PropertyDescriptor`s" (1 per column/property), which provide access to the underlying data (when supplied with an `object`), and information about the member itself (name, type, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Most controls can bind to the IList interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx

Comment: that doesn't directly answer the question, since `DataTable` doesn't implement `IList`

Comment: @Marc - thanks, is it better to use an IListSource as rather than an IList for controls that take a datasource?

Comment: Neither; it is best to use `object` and *test* whether it is `IListSource` (if so use that), otherwise *test* whether it is `IList` - or just hand that logic over to winforms itself by using things like `BindingSource`

Answer (score 0):

[IBindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.aspx)

Comment: In the context of the question, note that `List<T>` *doesn't* implement `IBindingList`